# Efficient way to pass list to template for bootstrap grid

Tags: flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

## What is the best practice to pass data from routes to template so that it doesn't break the template?

I have a template that uses bootstrap grid that is N rows by 3 columns.

Currently I am calculating the number of rows required in routes, and passing a list to the template to iterate through using Jinja2. I am doing this because I can't seem to import `Math` in the template, or perform some of the basic python operations like `len(mylist)`

As a result of this "hack", I have to identify the elements using `3*row + i`. ***It works, but this hard-coding is triggering my OCD!***

Can any more seasoned developers share what you would do for such cases?

```
@app.route('grid')
def grid():
    items = Items.query.all()
    items_row = list(range(0, ceil(len(items)/3) )) # Because I cannot round-up on Jinja2
    ...

return render_template('grid.html', items=items, item_rows=item_rows)
```

```
{% for row in item_rows %}

{% if 3*row + 0 < items|length %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="{{ url_for('item', id=items[3*row + 0].id) }}"
                <h1>{{ items[3*row + 0].header }}</h1>
            </a>
            <a href="{{ url_for('item', id=items[3*row + 0].id) }}"
                <p>{{ items[3*row + 0].body }}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
   </div>
{% endif %}

{% if 3*row + 1 < items|length %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="{{ url_for('item', id=items[3*row + 1].id) }}"
                <h1>{{ items[3*row + 1].header }}</h1>
            </a>
            <a href="{{ url_for('item', id=items[3*row + 1].id) }}"
                <p>{{ items[3*row + 1].body }}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}


{% if 3*row + 2 < items|length %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="{{ url_for('item', id=items[3*row + 2].id) }}"
                <h1>{{ items[3*row + 2].header }}</h1>
            </a>
            <a href="{{ url_for('item', id=items[3*row + 2].id) }}"
                <p>{{ items[3*row + 2].body }}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I hope [this](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#assignments) and [this](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#math) helps

Comment: Checking it out @kellymandem

Comment: @Yelle How did or is it going?

Comment: @kellymandem I went through the docs, not sure how ```Set``` can be used in my context, but the math section is really helpful. I found some special variables under FOR loop such as ```loop.index()``` and ```loop.length``` that looks promising! Thanks for the pointers (:

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored my code:

- It is much more concise now
- It is also much harder to read / understand

```
{% set rows = 3 %}
{% set cols = 3 %}

{% for item in items %}

    {% if loop.index0 // rows != (loop.index0 - 1) // rows %}
        <div class="row">
    {% endif %}

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <a href="{{ url_for('item.html', id=item.id) }}">
                <h1>{{ item.header }}<h1>
            </a>
            <p>{{ item.body }}</p>
        </div>

    {% if loop.index0 % cols  == 2 %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```